# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS shuts down and restarts

Tags: 14.04, grub2, shutdown

This is my first question so I'll try to do my best.

I have a Gateway laptop and I wanted a change, so I downloaded, burnt and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from www.ubuntu.com/download.

Once it was installed, Ubuntu asked me to install updates to the system. I installed it and, since then, the laptop has serious problems to boot.

You see, I start the laptop using the power button and it displays the OEM logo, goes to a purple screen, and then it shuts down! Shuts down completely, like there was a blackout or some sort of power outage. Then, out of nowhere the laptop starts again, displays the OEM logo and opens GRUB. It lists: Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, and System setup. I highlight "Ubuntu" and press Enter, but it shuts down again.

When I select "Advanced options for Ubuntu", the system displays all Ubuntu "images" (if I can describe them as that). Some times it doesn't matter which one I choose, it happens the same over and over.

It seems like the more updated my laptop is, the more times to shut down/power on it takes to boot properly. Sometimes it doesn't boot quite well (wrong keyboard layout, no Wi-Fi, etc.) and I have to suffer it all again. The last time I tried to boot, it took 6-8 shutdowns.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Is my HDD too old for Ubuntu?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a start, perhaps you might state the architecture of your laptop (32 bit or 64 bit) and which corresponding version of Ubuntu you are trying to install.

Comment: Does any of these "images" always work?

Answer (score 0):

could you throw more insight on how the installation was done? I think it is during the Installation that you missed out a step.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @gnsr
I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Gateway NV52L06m, changed the initial 500GB HDD with a 160GB HDD, previously wiped with DBAN 2.6.6. From the beggining it never booted because I configured the laptop to run on Legacy BIOS. Until I found out I had to run the laptop using UEFI, but I had to enter a password for the HDD so the laptp runs UEFI without Secure Boot.
I installed Ubuntu right away and following instructions in some blogs on how to partition the HDD. Got the same shutting down problem, and decided to reinstall Ubuntu, "Install Ubuntu (OEM users)".

Comment: Almost every time I turn on the laptop, it displays "Scanning for Btrfs filesystems". But I still have the shutting down problem. I purged newer images according to http://markmcb.com/2013/02/04/cleanup-unused-linux-kernels-in-ubuntu/ and configured Ubuntu not to install any update.

Comment: @Graham, my laptop has a 64-bit architecture.
Hope it helps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @UTF-8, no image works properly.
Hope it helps. Thank you in advance.